# Mulesoft Dataweave transformation into MongoDB - Failed to transform "com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler"

Tags: java, mongodb, mule, mule-component

I am successfully retrieving records from my Alfresco ECM instance. When I try to push them into MongoDb I get the following:

Failed to transform from "com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler" to "org.bson.Document" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler

I am using Dataweave to convert the query records to Json, but I am not sure why this is occurring.

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="mongotestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/add" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cmis:query config-ref="CMIS__Configuration" statement="SELECT cmis:objectId,cmis:name,cmis:contentStreamLength,cmis:creationDate,cmis:lastModifiedBy, cmis:lastModificationDate from cmis:document where cmis:createdBy &lt;&gt; 'System'" doc:name="CMIS"/>
         <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
             <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.properties map {
    "size": $.values[2][0]
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
         </dw:transform-message>
         <mongo:insert-document config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="testCollection" doc:name="Mongo DB" document-ref="#[message.payload]"/>
     </flow>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<mongo:json-to-dbobject doc:name="Mongo DB"/>` before inserting into `Mongo`

Comment: Not working...Failed to transform from "java.lang.String" to "org.bson.Document" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: String

Your example works, but I have a array in my dataweave. My dataweave output is this document:

[ { "ItemID": "ca5a12ef-5e26-449b-a7da-5d63141fe90c;1.0", "size": 400 }, { "ItemID": "7b1a75a3-5ee4-4984-a31b-1e39d4d54288;1.0", "size": 297 }, { "ItemID": "9515e794-188f-41d7-bd56-dfb202b4ef5f;1.0", "size": 297 } ]

Shouldn't the mongo connector accept json?

Comment: I've updated transformer in my answer.. give it a shot

Comment: The other thing that confuses me is the output type defined of your weave transform is `application/json` and your error states that `com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler`. Looks like output of weave is not coming as `json`.Check your config one more time

Comment: I don't have the json-to-dbobject transformer, so that was a no go. It is really weird - I am forcing it to be JSON, but mongo is still not taking it :(

Comment: Hey - the resolution actually ended up being to uninstall Mongo 4.01 and reinstall 4.1 connector. UGH! But I appreciate your help - got me looking in the right place :).